# Capturing objects with JMockit and Kotlin

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, jmockit

I am using JMockit for quite some time already, and I really like it. However, I just ran into an issue I cannot seem to solve. See the snippet below for some Kotlin test code, testing Kotlin production code.

```
@Injectable
lateinit var experimentStorage: ExperimentStorage
...
val experimentCaptor = mutableListOf<Experiment>()
object : Verifications() {
    init {
        experimentStorage.save(withCapture(experimentCaptor))
    }
}
```

When I run my test I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: withCapture(experimentCaptor) must
>   not be null

I am 100% sure my production code exercises the storage correctly, because when I replace the capture like below, my test succeeds:

```
object : Verifications() {
    init {
        experimentStorage.save(withAny(experiment))
    }
}
```

Does anyone have experience capturing parameters in Kotlin with JMockit (1.28)? What am I doing wrong? I guess it has to do with the `init` block, since in Java you would use static space...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I was not able to find any way in Kotlin any solution for this problem. The problem lies with the static space. In Kotlin you have the `init` block where you must record your `Expectations`/`Verifications`, but JMockit actually expects this in static space (hence the `{{...}}` notation).

My workaround for now is to keep the captors in Java, so I have a `Captors` class in my java test sources that looks like this

```
public class Captors {

    public static List<Experiment> experimentStorage_save(ExperimentStorage experimentStorage) {
        final List<Experiment> captor = new ArrayList<>();
        new Verifications() {{
            experimentStorage.save(withCapture(captor));
        }};
        return captor;    
    }

    ...
}
```